# Automatically delete files when a record is updated in table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

i have a table which has the fields `attachment_id` and `file_path` ,file_path field stores the path from s3 bucket corresponding to the attachment id .
is there any way to initialize a method or call an event directly from the model to delete file from s3 when the data in `file_path` field is updated or deleted ?

Comment: You can create a database trigger that will copy the deleted records to a deleted table (or you can soft delete the records) and have a cron running that will check for the deleted records and delete those files from S3 Bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a method or helper inside or outside of that model which delete the file from S3 Bucket, then setup an observer to trigger it during updated or deleting

e.i.

On your model

```
class WhatEver extends Model  {

    public function deleteS3File( $path ) {
        // Delete code here 
    }
}
```

Then generate an Observer

```
php artisan make:observer WhatEverObserver --model=WhatEver
```

then you can call that method on `updated` and `deleting` event

```
class WhatEverObserver  {

    // Runs when model is updated
    public function updated(WhatEver $whatEvah) {

        // Only trigger is file_path column is changed
        if ( $whatEvah->isDirty('file_path') ) {

            //Get the previous file_path record
            $oldPath = $whatEvah->getOriginal('file_path');

            //delete the previous file_path
            $whatEvah->deleteS3File( $oldPath );

        }
    }

    // Delete the file_path during model deletion
    public function deleting( WhatEver $whatEvah ) {
        $whatEvah->deleteS3File( $whatEvah->file_path );
    }
}
```

Make sure to check out [Observer docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#observers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$dispatchesEvents`.

Create an event and then, in your model:

```
class ClassName extends Model
{
    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'updated' => EventName::class
    ];
}
```

Check this out for more information: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events